# Crank-Nicolson Scheme equivalent to a forward and backward Euler method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, eulers-method

I am trying to show that, for the equation

$$y'+\alpha y=0$$

alternating between a forward Euler method step for $y_{2n}$ and a backward Euler step for $y_{2n+1}$ with time-step $h$ is equivalent to

$$y_{n+1}=\frac{1-\alpha h}{1+\alpha h}y_n$$

I have that

$$y_1 = y_0 + h(-\alpha y_0) = (1-\alpha h)y_0$$

How exactly $(1+\alpha h)$ works into this I don't see.  If I just press forward anyway, using the trapezoid rule for the backward Euler step next, and call $\hat{y}_n$ the approximation of $y_n$ using the forward Euler method, I get

$$y_2 = y_1 + h\left(\frac{y_1 + \hat{y}_2}{2}\right)$$

I'm kind of doing this *a priori* but that seems right to me: the trapezoid rule is to multiply the change in the $x$-axis by the average of the bases which are $y_1$ and $y_2$.  This becomes

$$y_2 = y_1 + h\left(\frac{y_1+(1-\alpha h)y_1}{2}\right) = \left( 1 + h\left(\frac{2-\alpha h}{2}\right)\right)y_1$$

This doesn't seem to be shaping up to the form I'm supposed to be getting.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It seems you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @mathreadler It's at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(z) = -\alpha z$, so $y' = f(y)$.

The forward Euler method is

$y_{n+1} = y_n + hf(y_n) =y_n -h\alpha y_n$, and the the backwards Euler method is 
$y_{n+1} =y_n + hf(y_{n+1}) =y_n -h\alpha y_{n+1}$

So we have $y_2 = y_1 + hf(y_2) = y_1-h\alpha y_2$ and $y_1 =y_0 + hf(y_0) =  y_0 -h\alpha y_0$

So putting this to gether we get $(1+h\alpha)y_2 = y_1 = (1-h\alpha )y_0$, or

$$y_2 = \frac{1-h\alpha}{1+h\alpha} y_0$$

Now you can generalize this and fin

$$y_{2n} = \frac{1-h\alpha}{1+h\alpha} y_{2(n-1)}$$

so in your solution $h$ probably only refers to half a time step.

Comment: Wait, I keep getting the wrong thing here, and I've been trying to trace down the reason.  I think it's that I'm not sure $y_2=y_1+hf(y_2) = y_1-h\alpha y_2$, as I believe at this point we should be using the trapezoid rule for the approximation, no?

Comment: What is unclear aobut this equation? Also why would you want to use the *trapeziod rule*? Your task only asks for implicit and explicit Euler. The result in the end is indeed equivalent to the trapezoid rule.

Comment: Nevermind, I think you're probably right to only use the rectangle approximation rather than the trapezoid approximation since that would explain everything.

Comment: I was under the impression that "backward Euler" just meant the trapezoid rule, since that's sort of how it's presented in my book--but after some online research I realize that's not so.

Comment: Backward Euler usually refers to the implicit Euler (and fwd to the explicit).